# install gsuit market place app using API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

**Query 1 :**

I have published my app in Gsuit Market place,what I want any admin can install my app by mine platform ie if he can install app (*mine published*) without going [Gsuit marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/).

So is there any Gsuit API for the same by using it we can install app on the behalf of him (*Admin who wants to install App*).

**Query 2 :**

This there any API why which we can fetch all the users those installed my published app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1**

This feature doesn't exist yet, not even mentioned in [Control user installation of Marketplace apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6089179?hl=en).

**Query 2**

Don't think there is. Even Google Analytics API only show [daily active users](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6171863?hl=en#datas) and not the specific users themselves.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.